# Why does deleting a conflicted file break a project?

Tags: git, openssl

I've had this happen to me three times now, and I'd like to try to fix it rather than deleting the project and re-cloning it. See, for example, [openssl-dev, link error [heartbeat_test] Error 2](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/openssl-testing/L6tMFChuIRY/WK1KJC49lDkJ).

I have [openssl-dev](https://www.openssl.org/source/repos.html) cloned via `git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git`.

Today, I did a `git pull` and it failed because of conflicting files. To resolve the conflicts, I performed:

```
rm apps/Makefile
rm crypto/engine/Makefile
rm crypto/evp/Makefile
rm ssl/Makefile
rm test/Makefile
```

After deleting the conflicts, the `git pull` succeeded and I attempted build.

Now, here's where I get lost. The build fails with duplicate symbols (shown below). It fails if I perform a complete clean and make (`dclean` is OpenSSL's version of `dist-clean`):

```
make clean && make dclean && export KERNEL_BITS=64 && ./config && make
```

And it fails if I toss in a make depend:

```
make clean && make dclean && export KERNEL_BITS=64 && ./config && make depend && make
```

I *thought* there might be some object files lying around after the clean, but there were none:

```
$ find . -iname *.o
$
```

If I perform a fresh clone, then everything works as expected.

What is the difference between the `git clone` and the `git pull` (with a clean and make) that would cause this problem?

Or what is the problem with git, and how do I resolve it?

---

```
openssl-git$ make clean && make dclean && export KERNEL_BITS=64 && \
    ./config && make depend && make
...
cc -I.. -I../include  -I../fips -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H 
-arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT 
-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM 
-DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM   -c -o heartbeat_test.o 
heartbeat_test.c

cc -I.. -I../include  -I../fips -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H 
-arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT 
-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM 
-DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM   -c -o testutil.o testutil.c

( :; LIBDEPS="${LIBDEPS:--Wl,-search_paths_first ../libssl.a ../libcrypto.a  }"; 
LDCMD="${LDCMD:-cc}"; LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS:--DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN 
-DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT 
-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM 
-DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM}"; LIBPATH=`for x in $LIBDEPS; do 
echo $x; done | sed -e 's/^ *-L//;t' -e d | uniq`; LIBPATH=`echo $LIBPATH | sed -e 's/ /:/g'`; 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBPATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LDCMD} ${LDFLAGS} -o ${APPNAME:=heartbeat_test} 
heartbeat_test.o testutil.o ${LIBDEPS} )

duplicate symbol _main in:
    heartbeat_test.o
    testutil.o

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
make[1]: *** [heartbeat_test] Error 2
make: *** [build_tests] Error 1
```

---

Because this has happened multiple times in the past, I know this is *not* a one-off problem.

I added the [openssl](/questions/tagged/openssl) tag because it's the project, but I'm pretty sure the underlying problem is with git.

I saved the project rather than deleting it, so I can tar it and upload it for inspection (if needed).

Finally:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.8.5
BuildVersion:   12F45
```

---

Below, `openssl-git` is where my copy of OpenSSL is located. It has my mods and tweaks. `openssl-git-test` is the fresh clone for testing. I ran `find . -name '*.save' -exec rm -rf {} \;` before diff'ing.

```
$ diff --brief -r openssl-git/ openssl-git-test/
Only in openssl-git/: .DS_Store
Only in openssl-git/.git: FETCH_HEAD
Only in openssl-git/.git: ORIG_HEAD
Files openssl-git/.git/index and openssl-git-test/.git/index differ
Files openssl-git/.git/logs/HEAD and openssl-git-test/.git/logs/HEAD differ
Files openssl-git/.git/logs/refs/heads/master and openssl-git-test/.git/logs/refs/heads/master differ
Files openssl-git/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD and openssl-git-test/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD differ
Only in openssl-git/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: OpenSSL_0_9_8-stable
Only in openssl-git/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: OpenSSL_1_0_0-stable
Only in openssl-git/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable
Only in openssl-git/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable
Only in openssl-git/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: master
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 00
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 02
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 05
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 07
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 08
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 09
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 0a
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 0e
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 0f
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 13
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 18
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 1b
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 1c
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 1d
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 23
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 24
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 25
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 28
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 2a
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 2c
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 36
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 37
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 38
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 3e
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 3f
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 42
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 44
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 4a
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 54
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 58
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 5c
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 5d
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 60
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 61
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 63
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 66
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 67
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 68
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 6e
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 6f
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 71
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 72
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 78
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 79
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 7b
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 80
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 82
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 84
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 87
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 88
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 8d
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 8e
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 99
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: 9f
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: a0
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: a3
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: a4
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: a8
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: a9
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: ae
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: af
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: b2
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: b5
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: ba
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: bc
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: bd
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: be
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: c4
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: c5
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: c6
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: d3
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: d5
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: d6
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: d7
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: da
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: db
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: de
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: e0
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: e3
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: e7
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: e8
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: e9
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: ed
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: ef
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: f2
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: fa
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: fb
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects: fc
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects/pack: pack-663dfba6981c559658fb9253e5456938cd330c97.idx
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects/pack: pack-663dfba6981c559658fb9253e5456938cd330c97.pack
Only in openssl-git-test/.git/objects/pack: pack-97e4b04a1ce519e33653e4f4ef941fed44f53332.idx
Only in openssl-git-test/.git/objects/pack: pack-97e4b04a1ce519e33653e4f4ef941fed44f53332.pack
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects/pack: pack-a5611b625ffa369803ca57e5d198864c4c3933a4.idx
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects/pack: pack-a5611b625ffa369803ca57e5d198864c4c3933a4.pack
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects/pack: pack-feccfacff9cc5bff523280a162d04c2c3813bba8.idx
Only in openssl-git/.git/objects/pack: pack-feccfacff9cc5bff523280a162d04c2c3813bba8.pack
Files openssl-git/.git/packed-refs and openssl-git-test/.git/packed-refs differ
Files openssl-git/.git/refs/heads/master and openssl-git-test/.git/refs/heads/master differ
Only in openssl-git/.git/refs/remotes/origin: OpenSSL_0_9_8-stable
Only in openssl-git/.git/refs/remotes/origin: OpenSSL_1_0_0-stable
Only in openssl-git/.git/refs/remotes/origin: OpenSSL_1_0_1-stable
Only in openssl-git/.git/refs/remotes/origin: OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable
Only in openssl-git/.git/refs/remotes/origin: master
Only in openssl-git/.git/refs/tags: OpenSSL_0_9_8zb
Only in openssl-git/.git/refs/tags: OpenSSL_1_0_0n
Only in openssl-git/.git/refs/tags: OpenSSL_1_0_1i
Files openssl-git/doc/apps/ciphers.pod and openssl-git-test/doc/apps/ciphers.pod differ
Files openssl-git/doc/apps/pkcs8.pod and openssl-git-test/doc/apps/pkcs8.pod differ
Only in openssl-git/engines: e_padlock-x86.s
Only in openssl-git/: s3_enc.c.diff
Files openssl-git/ssl/s3_clnt.c and openssl-git-test/ssl/s3_clnt.c differ
Files openssl-git/ssl/s3_enc.c and openssl-git-test/ssl/s3_enc.c differ
Files openssl-git/ssl/s3_lib.c and openssl-git-test/ssl/s3_lib.c differ
Files openssl-git/ssl/tls1.h and openssl-git-test/ssl/tls1.h differ
```

Comment: Why are you removing files?  That's not a good way of resolving conflicts.  For that matter, git doesn't believe they *are* resolved, if you just remove them: `Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.`

Comment: @torek - *"why are you removing files?"* - to resolve conflicts. I don't care about my local changes. So I simply discard them and use the project's version of the file.

Comment: To use the project's version, you must `git checkout` the project's version.  Removing the file just makes git think you want the file completely gone.  (But you have to `git rm` the file to resolve the merge conflict in favor of "remove", or use something like `git add -u .` to make it pick up on the work-tree change.)  I think perhaps you want `git checkout --theirs` to resolve these.

Comment: @torek - I don't use `git checkout`. I perform a `git clone`, and then I go to work. I can see changes with `git diff`. When I need to update, I perform `git pull`. When there's a conflict, I perform `rm` and then a `git pull` to go back to the project's copy of the file. I don't manage copies, I don't manage branches, I don't submit patches and I don't share my changes with anyone. I don't do anything other than keep my copy in sync with the distribution's copy (the ONE TRUE VERSION of the sources).

Comment: You're fighting git's basic assumptions here.  If you run `git clone` (without `-n`), you *do* use `git checkout`: it does one at the end.  If you just want to extract someone else's code base while ignoring the fact that there's a git repo in the way, you may want to use a pure mirror, then have git extract a particular commit into some other (empty) work-tree: `git clone --mirror ...` followed by `mkdir /over/there; git --work-tree=/over/there checkout master`.  This mirror is then used only as a slave of "their" repo, to avoid re-cloning.

Comment: Thanks @torek. So when I remove a file and then do a `git pull`, does git stop making the assumption? Or maybe better: what simply gets a copy of the ONE TRUE VERSION so I can work on it with out assumptions or other hassles? On occasion, I need to delete a file with a conflict and go back to using the ONE TRUE VERSION's copy of a file. What I'm really looking for is `svn checkout` and `svn update`, but I don't know how to express it in git (other similar SO questions state to use `git clone` and `git pull`, but it appears they were wrong).

Comment: `git pull` will not overwrite local changes that don't conflict. If you want git to throw away a locally changed file in favor of the file from pristine sources you need to use `git checkout -- <file>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing a bit based on some other items found in a few places, but it sounds like:

- You're using git to clone something just to get some version of it, which you intend not to edit.
- The thing you're cloning edits *itself*, in its own source tree, in its normal course of operation.  This plays rather badly with git, or indeed most version control systems.  (The "right" way to do this with VCS-es is to keep the variable, ever-changing, self-generated, non-source-controlled stuff in a separate area—this can be as simple as separate files in the regular source area, that you can tell the VCS to ignore, as with git's `.gitignore` files.)
- For someone using svn, they can "cheat": the repository itself can be stored way over there (imagine arrow pointing off into The Net), and when the thing you're working with edits itself, you just remove things and ask it to check them out again into your work tree.  So this winds up being only semi-visible.  With git, however, you automatically have the repository *right here*, so the VCS sees that you have changed things and insists that you force it to throw your changes out, before it can update anything.

There are several (perhaps many) solutions to the problem.  The best would be to treat things the "right way" noted above, but that requires co-operation at the other end.  That leaves several work-arounds:

1. Be explicit to git: "wipe my stuff out."

   ```
   git reset --hard && git fetch && git merge
   ```

   The `reset --hard` means "wipe out all my changes".  (You may also want a `git clean -fdx` as well, to remove build products.  Or, you can leave them there, and reset only those files git knows about, i.e., the ones it extracted originally from your clone-step checkout.)  Be sure you really mean it; this has no "oops, wait, I changed my mind" option.

   The `git fetch && git merge` step can be abbreviated as `git pull` (although they're not quite identical, especially in older versions of git).  This is a key to understanding what's going on here: **`pull` is just `fetch` followed by `merge`.**  You're using `git checkout` and all of git's version-control stuff, and when you remove files, git gets all helpful<sup>1</sup> and insistent on you saving your work, because it's quite certain you're attempting to version-control your own changes, and meld them in some way with theirs ("them" being whoever you `fetch` from).
2. Keep git's repository separate from your source-and-build-tree, as if you're not using a version control system at all.  In particular, you can make git "act like" SVN by using a mirror (or a bare clone).  This gives you the repository locally, but (at least for the mirror) in a way that you never touch except to update it from the remote version:

   ```
   git clone --mirror git://whatever... local-clone.git
   ```

   Then, use the mirror to extract the latest version into an empty tree:

   ```
   cd local-clone; git --work-tree=/somewhere/else checkout master
   ```

   or:

   ```
   cd /somewhere; mkdir else; cd else
   git --git-dir=/path/to/local/clone.git checkout master
   ```

   (Or, you can use `git --work-tree=... reset --hard` or `git --git-dir=... reset --hard` to get some files back to their original state, but then you might as well use the first approach.)  The main advantage here is that since the git repository is "far enough away" from the work-tree, no one will *accidentally* attempt to use git to do work in `/somewhere/else`, thinking they're getting all the usual git guarantees.

If you use the `--mirror` method (which now I think is probably more work than the first method), note that `git fetch` will update your (mirrored) branches directly.  In this case there's nothing to merge, and in fact you *can't* use the mirror to hold your own changes: they will be lost when you run `git fetch --prune` (or `git remote update -p`) to pick up new changes from the remote.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or some less printable adjective. :-)

Comment: Thanks again Torek. The problem ended up being with `make dclean`. It whacked the `test/` directory. I'm not sure where the duplicate symbols come from (i.e., what's broken in the config or Makefiles), but if I restore the `test/` directory, then the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in a related question: [Can I use the files present after a git clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469996/can-i-use-the-files-present-after-a-git-clone).

The problem was `make dclean` deleted the `test/` directory (thanks @hvd). `dclean` is the OpenSSL equivalent of `distclean`. Unfortunately, the project is full of cruft and a `diff` after `dclean` is nearly useless (see [Bug #3492: Make dclean creates a 630K+ git diff](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3492)).

The problem does not appear to be related to git. (Though I admit I use it in a very simplified manner, and many folks don't agree with the simplicity).