# Can I use the files present after a git clone?

Tags: openssl, makefile, git-clone

I'm trying to understand a make problem, and I'm not sure what is going on. I'm not sure if I'm experiencing a problem with make or a problem git.

If I perform:

```
$ git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git openssl-git
```

Then I get what appears to be OpenSSL's source files:

```
$ cd openssl-git
$ ls
ACKNOWLEDGMENTS INSTALL.VMS     README          demos       os2
CHANGES         INSTALL.W32     README.ASN1     doc         perl
CHANGES.SSLeay  INSTALL.W64     README.ECC      e_os.h      shlib
Configure       INSTALL.WCE     README.ENGINE   e_os2.h     ssl
...
```

Those files look *exactly* like I get when I download an OpenSSL tarball and unpack it.

Are those files *not* usable? Am I not allowed to perform a `make` on them?

---

The reason I'm asking such a simple question is: I open `Configure`, I modify one of the configure lines, and then I perform a clean, configure and make. Make subsequently fails. When I ask about it, I'm told I'm not using git correctly.

Here are the folks telling me make is OK and I'm using git incorrectly (from the OpenSSL Testing mailing list): [openssl-dev, link error [heartbeat_test] Error 2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openssl-testing/L6tMFChuIRY).

Here are the folks telling me I'm using git incorrectly (from Stack Overflow): [Why does deleting a conflicted file break a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336115/why-does-deleting-a-conflicted-file-break-a-project).

**Note**: I experience the same problem in both SO question, except this question uses a fresh clone.

---

```
# Standard checkout
git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git openssl-git
cd openssl-git

# This is a false start. A config is needed to create a Makefile
export KERNEL_BITS=64
./config

# Clean up developer checked-in cruft
make clean && make dclean
# Open Configure, find debug-darwin64-x86_64-cc, change -g2 to -g3

./Configure debug-darwin64-x86_64-cc no-ssl2 enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128
make depend
make

...
duplicate symbol _main in:
    heartbeat_test.o
    testutil.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
make[1]: *** [heartbeat_test] Error 2
make: *** [build_tests] Error 1
```

I can also change `./Configure debug-darwin64-x86_64-cc no-ssl2 enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128` to `./config no-ssl2 enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128` with the same results. The `export KERNEL_BITS=64` ensures I get the 64-bit Darwin configuration (`darwin64-x86_64-cc`).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I'm suffering a disconnect". It suggests to me that `git clone` failed, but reading the rest of your question, I don't think it did. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: "Make subsequently fails" What commands do you run? What error do you get? I think the problem here is with how you are running `config` and/or `make`, not with `git`.

Comment: @hvd: *"I don't understand what you mean by 'I'm suffering a disconnect'".* - I'm told that I'm not using git correctly. But I fail to see how I am using git incorrectly. I seem to be suffering a major disconnect.

Comment: @jww Oh, I see what you mean now. That's not a common use of the word "disconnect" here, that pretty much always refers to a network connection. Thanks for clarifying. I cannot judge whether it will be equally confusing to others, but if you think it might be, you may want to reword your question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: *" What commands do you run?"* - `./config && make clean && make dclean && export KERNEL_BITS=64 && ./config && make depend && make`. The first `config` is present to produce a `Makefile`. With a `Makefile` present, I can perform a `make clean && make dclean`. Once everything is distro clean, I then proceed to configure and make.

Comment: @jww Yes, you're right. I had deleted my comment after I did indeed see the exact same error message when I tried the exact same commands you included in your comment, without any local changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use that clone to do a `make`.

But note that [`INSTALL`](http://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=INSTALL;h=610f7dad268a0b9ec6f9977b8c64310579032a54;hb=HEAD) advices to use `./config`, not `Configure` directly.
You can modify `Configure`, but you should do a `./config` after, not `./Configure` (unless you want to configure OpenSSL for your operating system manually).

Comment: Thanks VonC. I get the same error with both `config` and `Configure`. I think the problem is in one of those Makefies somewhere, and not with git. I'm frustrated because I keep being told its with the way I use git.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the problem isn't with your use of Git at all, and is because of the OpenSSL Makefiles. The problem is that `make dclean` removes required files. Straight after you run `make dclean`, `git status` will show that some C files in the `test/` directory have been removed. Restoring those files after they have been removed is sufficient to make it work:

```
git checkout -- 'test/*.c'
```

What's throwing people off is that you are using Git in ways it is not normally recommended to be used (but actually may well be commonly used), and in ways that can easily cause very similar problems. Like you did in the comments here, though, the simple way to show others that the problem isn't with Git, is to explain the real problem in a way that does not rely on any questionable Git commands. In your question here, you've shown the exact commands that lead to the error message, that can be run straight after `git clone` without any further user input. I suspect you would have received more useful answers to your other questions if you had done the same there.

Comment: Thanks @hvd. So we're on the same page: I don't do checkouts - I use the ONE TRUE SOURCES from OpenSSL. OpenSSL is not like the kernel. OpenSSL has ONE TRUE SOURCES.  Their single source model is more suitable for subversion, but they don't use it.

Comment: @jww Wrong link, that's the question I did post an answer to. The first half of my answer is not really what you asked here, but also, I think, not really what you asked in your other SO question. It is what you asked on the OpenSSL mailing list, but I'd rather not post there. :) The second half of my answer seems more appropriate to me here than on your other SO question, so I'd be happy to leave it as it is.

Comment: 2nd try (with a correct link) ... Would you like to provide an answer at [Why does deleting a conflicted file break a project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336115/why-does-deleting-a-conflicted-file-break-a-project)? I think that's the question you answered. I think you deserve the credit even in this case.

Comment: By the way, how did you find *"... the problem is that make dclean removes required files"*. The git diff is so large after a `dclean` its useless. I opened a bug report on it when trying to trouble shoot this. [Bug #3492: Make dclean creates a 630K+ git diff](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3492).

Comment: @jww That isn't visible without logging in and I don't have an account there, but since I already suspected something was getting deleted that shouldn't be (since the point of `dclean` is to remove things), I merely had to look at the output of `git status`.